# Why does RxJS interval begin from last value but not from "0"?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, observable

I need to reset my custom timer to "0 seconds" when I click the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button. But when I press <kbd>Start</kbd> my timer continues from last value, not from "0 seconds".

```
const [time, setTime] = useState (0);
const [timerOn, setTimerOn ] = useState (false);

let observable$ = interval(1000);
    
  let subscription = observable$.subscribe(result =>{
    if (timerOn) {
      setTime(result);
    }
  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [timerOn]);

return (
<div>
{!timerOn && (
        <button onClick={() => setTimerOn(true)}>Start</button>
        )}
{ time > 0 && (
    <button onClick={() => setTime(0)}>Reset</button>
    )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Let's take a look at the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button:

```
<button onClick={() => setTime(0)}>Reset</button>
```

When you click this button it runs the following function:

```
() => setTime(0)
```

This just sets the `time` state back to `0`. That's all. It doesn't touch the subscription to the interval observable at all. As a result, the interval subscription will continue emitting numbers in sequence which is why it appears to continue from the last value.

## Solution

Your reset function will have to do more than just setting `time` back to `0`. What it does exactly will be up to your specific use case. For example, it could end the subscription, end the subscription and create a new one, or reset the existing subscription. I've included a code example for a basic way of ending the subscription:

```js
const {
  StrictMode,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  useState,
} = React;
const { interval } = rxjs;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

function useCounter() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);
  const observable$ = interval(1000);
  const subscription = useRef();

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    setTimerOn(true);

    subscription.current = observable$.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      setTime(result);
    });
  });

  const stop = useCallback(() => {
    setTimerOn(false);
    subscription.current.unsubscribe();
  });

  const reset = useCallback(() => {
    setTime(0);
    setTimerOn(false);
    subscription.current.unsubscribe();
  });

  return {
    time,
    timerOn,
    start,
    stop,
    reset
  };
}

function Counter() {
  const { time, timerOn, start, stop, reset } = useCounter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{time}</h1>
      <br />
      {!timerOn && <button onClick={() => start()}>Start</button>}
      {time > 0 && <button onClick={() => reset()}>Reset</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <Counter />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```